# can 5 alpha reductase inhibitor drugs work for life or do they lose effectivness

Tags: medications, side-effects

does 5 alpha reductase inhibitor  drugs like finasteride and dutasteride losses their effectiveness over time, and why do some drugs like Hiv regimen work prolonged time without tolerance and other drugs ex. antidepressant drugs have the tolerance issue after short time.